# Unit testing for uncurry in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ounit

my implementation so far I cant seem to understand where is the issue

```
let uncurry_test1 _test_ctxt =
    assert_equal
    uncurry  f  (4 3)
    7
```

Comment: You should take the time to describe what you are trying the achieve, and what issue you are encountering. Currently, you have yet to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

The `assert_equal` function from the OUnit2 library has type,

```
val assert_equal :
  ?ctxt:test_ctxt ->
  ?cmp:('a -> 'a -> bool) ->
  ?printer:('a -> string) ->
  ?pp_diff:(Format.formatter -> ('a * 'a) -> unit) ->
  ?msg:string -> 'a -> 'a -> unit
```

There are only two non-keyword parameters, but you're applying it to four. I would suggest you read at least the [OCaml tutorial](https://ocaml.org/manual/coreexamples.html) and learn how functions are applied in OCaml. For example, the piece of code `(4 3)` in OCaml means apply `4` to `3`, where "apply F to Y" means call the function F with argument X. Obviously, `4` is not a function (spoiler, it is a number), so this code doesn't make sense and raises a type error.

It is hard to guess from the information that you provided what is the type of `uncurry` and what is the type of `f`, but probably you meant something like this,

```
assert_equal 7 (uncurry f 4 3)
```

Which says, that we expect `7` when we uncurry the function `f` and apply it to `4` and `3`.

where `f` is probably `curry (+)`